# Rtk query typescript giving warning while showing errors

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, rtk-query

I'm using React Ts, and Rtk query. I'm trying to show the API response error on the UI. It's working but giving me a warning. It's telling me to set the error type for the response errors. How can I add an error type for response errors? Or are there any other solutions? This is how I'm showing the error.

```js
const [login, { isLoading, isError, error }] = useLoginMutation();

return (
    <div>
      {isError && (
        <div className="bg-neRed-200 text-neRed-900 font-medium py-1 px-2 text-sm rounded">
          {error?.data?.error}
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
)
```

Basically, it's giving me this error:

```
Property 'data' does not exist on type 'FetchBaseQueryError | SerializedError'.
  Property 'data' does not exist on type 'SerializedError'.
```

And this is how it's looking on the code editor:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As you see, there two different types:

1. `FetchBaseQueryError`
2. `SerializedError`

These 2 have different return types. `SerializedError` return type is:

```
export interface SerializedError {
  name?: string
  message?: string
  stack?: string
  code?: string
}
```

As you can see, there is no `data` property within.

So if you want to get only `FetchBaseQueryError` errors, you can check as this to be ensured:

```
if ('data' in error) {}
```

You can read more here:

[RTK-Query Error Handling](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage-with-typescript#type-safe-error-handling)

Comment: I also tried this, but it's giving me another warning. `Property 'error' does not exist on type '{}'.`. I've attached an image for more details: [https://i.ibb.co/Fn6bk8X/Screenshot-2.png](https://i.ibb.co/Fn6bk8X/Screenshot-2.png)

Comment: @SabbirZzaman If you're checking `data` in `error`, so it's `FetchBaseQueryError` and if you consider the related type, `data` is `undefined`, `string` and `unknown` and logically it should throw errors. So I encourage you to use `error?.data`.